# Why did my drawsana instance doesn't respond on Uigesturerecognizer on IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, draw

I have got a class using Drawsana. I want my DrawsanaView to respond to a PinchGesture, but it doesn't. For example if I use this line for the view:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self,
                                             action: #selector(tapView))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

it works!

But when I use:

```
let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                            action: #selector(self.pinchGesture))
self.drawsanaView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture))
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide any error messages you are receiving?

Comment: it doesn't provide any comment, only nothing happen